why the Destructor of an object of square class is called repeatedly on arrow key press in OpenGL GLUT application?
here is the entire code. below it i explain what i'm facing
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include<GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include<GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<time.h>

typedef struct point
{
   float x;
   float y;
}point;
typedef struct color
{
   float r;
   float g;
   float b;
}color;


int number_of_segments = 200;

float logX = 100;
float logY = 100;

int PhyWidth = 1000;
int PhyHeight = 1000;

int windowPosX = 500;
int windowPosY = 500;

float centerX = logX / 2;
float centerY = logY / 2;
int alphaX = 0;
int alphaY = 0;


typedef unsigned char u8;

class square
{
    private:

        point* pts = new point[4];
        float width;
        float height;
        bool  filled;
        float max_x;
        float min_x;
        float max_y;
        float min_y;
        int id;
        color colour = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
        bool main;
    public:
        square(point pt, int width, int height, bool filled, bool main)
        {
            this->width = width;
            this->height = height;
            this->filled = filled;
            this->main = main;
            float half_width = width/2;
            float half_height = height/2;
            min_x = pt.x - half_width;
            max_x = pt.x + half_width;
            min_y = pt.y - half_height;
            max_y = pt.y + half_height;
            this->pts[0] = {min_x, min_y};
            this->pts[1] = {max_x, min_y};
            this->pts[2] = {max_x, max_y};
            this->pts[3] = {min_x, max_y};
        }
        square(point pt, int width, int height, bool main, color colour, int id)
        {
            this->id = id;
            this->width = width;
            this->height = height;
            this->main = main;
            this->colour = colour;
            float half_width = width/2;
            float half_height = height/2;
            min_x = pt.x - half_width;
            max_x = pt.x + half_width;
            min_y = pt.y - half_height;
            max_y = pt.y + half_height;
            this->pts[0] = {min_x, min_y};
            this->pts[1] = {max_x, min_y};
            this->pts[2] = {max_x, max_y};
            this->pts[3] = {min_x, max_y};
        }

        ~square()
        {
            std::cout<<"square eaten!"<<id<<"\n";
            // delete pts;
        }
        point* get_pts()
        {
            return this->pts;
        }

        void draw()
        {
            int alphaX_copy = 0;
            int alphaY_copy = 0;
            if(main)
            {
                alphaX_copy = alphaX;
                alphaY_copy = alphaY;
            }
            glColor4f(colour.r, colour.g, colour.b, 1);
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                glVertex2f(this->pts[0].x + alphaX_copy, this->pts[0].y + alphaY_copy);
                glVertex2f(this->pts[1].x + alphaX_copy, this->pts[1].y + alphaY_copy);
                glVertex2f(this->pts[2].x + alphaX_copy, this->pts[2].y + alphaY_copy);
                glVertex2f(this->pts[3].x + alphaX_copy, this->pts[3].y + alphaY_copy);
            glEnd();
        }
        static bool intersected_squares(square big_square, square small_square)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if( small_square.pts[i].x > (big_square.min_x + alphaX) && small_square.pts[i].x < (big_square.max_x + alphaX))
                {
                    // means in the range of x
                    if(small_square.pts[i].y > (big_square.min_y + alphaY) && small_square.pts[i].y < (big_square.max_y + alphaY))
                    {
                        std::cout<<"Bingo!";
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
};




square big_square({centerX,centerY}, 20, 20, true, {1.0, 0, 0}, 1);
std::vector<square> little_squares;

void display(void);
void init(void);

void special_keyboard(int key, int x, int y);


void draw_text(char* str, point pt);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float r,g,b;
    int x,y;
    srand(time(0));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        r = std::rand() % 256;
        g = std::rand() % 256;
        b = std::rand() % 256;
        r /= 255.0;
        g /= 255.0;
        b /= 255.0;
        x = std::rand() % 80;
        y = std::rand() % 80;
        point p = {x,y};
        color colour = {r,g,b};
        little_squares.emplace_back(p, 6, 6, false, colour, i);
        std::cout<<"i hope this doesn't repeat itself\n";
    }


    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowSize(PhyWidth, PhyHeight);
    glutInitWindowPosition(windowPosX,windowPosY);
    glutCreateWindow("Shehab");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(special_keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();


    return 0;
}

void display(void)
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    big_square.draw();
    for(int i = 0; i < little_squares.size(); i++)
    {
        if(square::intersected_squares(big_square, little_squares[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        little_squares[i].draw();
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{

    glClearColor(0.0, 0, 1.0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0, logX, 0, logY);
}



void draw_text(char* str, point pt)
{
   glRasterPos2d(pt.x, pt.y);
   for (int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18,str[i]);
}


void special_keyboard(int key, int x, int y)
{
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    {
        alphaY += 5;
    }
    else if(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        alphaY -= 5;
    }
    else if(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        alphaX += 5;
    }
    else if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        alphaX -= 5;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}


i'm trying to make a big square that the user moves with arrow keys and when it reach any of the smaller squares it eats it. the problem that i face is that each time i move the destructor of each object is executed and i don't know why, besides the first few times because of the vector reallocation. that behavior disappears when i remove line 201
        if(square::intersected_squares(big_square, little_squares[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }

so i don't understand what causes this.
I've tried to debug with gdb but i didn't get anything, and i don't know how should i tackle debugging with this kind of application. I know that it might work if i change from using vector to another data structure but i wanted to know what causes this behavior since there is nothing that should trigger the reallocation for the vector.

static bool intersected_squares(square big_square, square small_square) -- Quite simply, you are passing square by value, thus temporary copies are made that need to be destroyed.   Your square class does not have correct copy semantics.  Eiither implement the rule of 3, or use std::array<points, 4> pts; instead of point* pts = new point[4];, or pass square by const reference, not by-value.  Also, int main() { square s(1,2,3,true,true);  square s2 = s; } -- even that small program shows the error.

Secondly, if you want to print a message in the destructor, you should be printing the value of this.  If you had done that, you would have seen that the objects being destroyed are not the ones you created, but the temporary ones being created by you passing square by-value.

Also, go to the Managing resources section at the "rule of 3" link.  You will see a class that looks similar to yours in terms of allocating memory, and only having a destructor.  Read that section carefully as to why your class is failing.

Side note: in C++ you don't have to do the typedef struct point { ... } point; dance. struct point { ... }; works just fine.

@PaulMcKenzie thank you so much for answering in detail like that, i thought objects would be passed by reference by default like in java.

@ShehabBadawy Unlike Java, C++ works with value-semantics, not reference semantics.  In C++, to pass by reference, you must explicitly state this: static bool intersected_squares(square& big_square, square& small_square).
